# Cannot build CastVideos-android, Error: Bad pathname

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, chromecast

I have cloned from github both the respositories CastVideos-android and CastCompanionLibrary-android to my AndroidStudioProjects folder with the names 'CastVideos' and 'CastCompanionLibrary'. When I attempt to build CastVideos, in Android Studio I get

```
Gradle 'CastVideos' project refresh failed
Error:Bad pathname
```

When I run 'gradlew.bat build' in the CastVideos directory, I get the below:

```
C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVideos>gradlew.bat build
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been depre
cated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'CastVideos'.
> Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVide
os\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CastVideos...\CastCompanionLibrary\unspecifi
ed\debug'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.701 secs

C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVideos>
```

This is my first attempt at using Android Studio after developing with Eclipse so I am a bit lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any spaces or strange charachter in that errored path?

Comment: C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVideos\build\ doesn't exist to begin with and neither does C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastCompanionLibrary\unspecified\debug.

Comment: Are these Android libraries that you are using? CastVideos and  CastCompanionLibrary

Comment: CastVideos is an example Android application that shows how to cast videos (https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/) and CastCompanionLibrary is a dependency of CastVideos (https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android)

Comment: Is it possible to show me your CastVideo project folder structure. I suspect that the CastCompanionLibrary was not imported properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know why. It is a Windows thing. It seems that Windows does not realize that '..' mean upper directory. that is why you have this path `"C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVide os\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CastVideos...\CastCompanionLibrary\unspecifi ed\debug"` I am running on the mac which seems to be working fine

I would suggest that you copy the whole CastCompanionLibrary into your CastVideo directory and then change `..:CastCompanionLibraries` to `:CastCompanionLibraries`

Comment: I had already renamed the CastCompanionLibrary-android folder to CastCompanionLibrary (so the dependency references and include would be correct) before trying to build CastVideos the first time.

Comment: I just start fresh on that project and I managed to run the it.

Comment: Is it possible to add a screenshot of what you see on Android Studio along with `build.gradle` open?

Comment: I must be missing something. How are you starting off? In my working directory I am running 'git clone https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android.git CastCompanionLibrary' followed by 'git clone https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android.git CastVideos' and then running 'gradlew.bat build' in workingdirectory\CastVideos

Comment: try gradlew.bat assembleDebug and see if that gives you the same error

Comment: Same error. Here is what I am seeing in Android Studio with build.gradle open. At the bottom is an output of the directory structure http://i.imgur.com/vsnH6mn.png

Comment: Mine is like this http://imgur.com/TzXPMN6. For some reasons Android Studio is not picking up CastCompanionLibrary as a module

Comment: Can I also see you `settings.gradle`. Also have you tried `gradlew.bat clean` before you make a build?

Comment: CastVideo\settings.gradle is a single line: include '..:CastCompanionLibrary' and 'gradlew.bat clean' throws the same error about not being able to normalize the path

Comment: I think I know why. It is a Windows thing. It seems that Windows does not realize that '..' mean upper directory. that is why you have this path "C:\Users\Tim\AndroidStudioProjects\CastVide
os\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\CastVideos...\CastCompanionLibrary\unspecifi
ed\debug" I am running on the mac which seems to be working fine

Comment: I could say go and buy a MAC :). Kidding aside I would suggest that you copy the whole CastCompanionLibrary into your CastVideo directory and then change `..:CastCompanionLibraries` to `:CastCompanionLibraries`

Comment: I wish I could talk myself into one htat easy :) I went ahead and did what you suggested and that worked. For building this on Windows I would consider that the solution

Answer (score 1):

Changing relative paths from `..:` to `./..:` in both `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` worked for me on Windows.